# Make ul list to look better no matter of li's heights

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Here is a simple html + css code:
https://jsfiddle.net/bxn72cyk/

The problem here is ul list doesn't look nice if one element has a different height than others.
How to fix this list no matter of each height with a css?

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 30%;
}

.different {
  height: 19px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li class="different">smaller height</li>
  <li>set it from the left</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>d</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

P.S. Setting li {min-height: 20px} is one of the possible solutions, but it's not applicable. Any other options? It's not applicable as the actual size of each button could be even smaller than 20px under some circumstances.

Comment: `display: flex`, `flex-wrap: wrap` for `ul`, and remove `height: 19px` from `.different` - will solve your problem? the question is not quite clear

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!

Comment: no problem, friend